# Circular Dependency -Table Insertion Error

Tags: sql, oracle, nested-table

I want to insert data into table but got below error..Can any one help me..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TEST_TYP FORCE IS OBJECT 
    ("id" VARCHAR(5000 NULL) 
NOT FINAL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TEST_TAB is table of REF TEST_TYP; 

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TEST1_TYP FORCE IS OBJECT 
    ("id" VARCHAR2(500) NULL,
     "extension" "TEST_TAB" NULL )
NOT FINAL;


CREATE TABLE "TEST_OBJ_TABLE" OF "TEST1_TYP"
NESTED TABLE "extension" STORE AS "Allin"
```

When I try to insert using this statementL

```
insert into "TEST_OBJ_TABLE" ("id","extension")
VALUES(
'0FE71A85',
"TEST_TAB"("TEST_TYP"( '0FE71A8'))
);
```

It throws this error

> Error at Command Line : 59 Column : 12
>   Error report -
>   SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected REF SUB_HWOW.TEST_TYP got SUB_HWOW.TEST_TYP
>   00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Comment: Why is that a circular dependency? The error says that the problem is that you're inserting an object rather than a ref to an object. So you need to decide whether the first table should actually be refs, and if so where the actual referenced objects are going to live?

Comment: Thanks Alex..To insert data into that table what I have to do..Can u correct my code..

Answer (score 0):

Changed the original answer. The quotes are doing you no favors - nor was calling your column names id. Removed the REF reference.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TEST_TYP FORCE IS OBJECT 
    (id1 VARCHAR(4000) NULL)
NOT FINAL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TEST_TAB is table of TEST_TYP; 

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TEST1_TYP FORCE IS OBJECT 
    (id2 VARCHAR2(500) NULL,
     extension TEST_TAB NULL )
NOT FINAL;


CREATE TABLE TEST_OBJ_TABLE OF TEST1_TYP
NESTED TABLE extension STORE AS Allin ;

insert into TEST_OBJ_TABLE ( ID2, EXTENSION)
VALUES(
'0FE71A85',
TEST_TAB(TEST_TYP( '0FE71A8'))
);

SELECT * FROM TEST_OBJ_TABLE ;
```

Comment: Thanks Brian..In previous question I forgot to include "TEST_TYP" declaration.Now I modified that.Can you help me now.WhileI tries to inserting data into table what I created it gave error like ""expected REF SUB_HWOW.TEST_TYP got SUB_HWOW.TEST_TYP" but I am  unaware of how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to modify object `TEST_TYP -> varchar2 has to be max 4000`.
   You have to store this object in db.
2. Create object table for TEST_TYP
   `create table t_for_test_type of TEST_TYP;`
3. To obtain object reference, the object have to be save in db table. In your case:

   declare
         v_ref_to_test_type1 ref TEST_TYP;
       begin 
        insert into t_for_test_type t values('abcd1') return ref(t) into v_ref_to_test_type1;
       end:
4. Join all parts together.

   declare 
     v_ref_to_test_type1 ref TEST_TYP;
     v_ref_to_test_type2 ref TEST_TYP;
   begin 
    insert into t_for_test_type t values('abcd1') return ref(t) into v_ref_to_test_type1;
    insert into t_for_test_type t values('abcd2') return ref(t) into v_ref_to_test_type2;
    insert into TEST_OBJ_TABLE values (TEST1_TYP('abcd',new TEST_TAB(v_ref_to_test_type1,v_ref_to_test_type2))); 
   end;
5. Query table. 
   `select t."id",x.column_value from TEST_OBJ_TABLE t, table(t."extension") x`  it returns id + ref to other object
6. Viewing the referenced object.
   `select t."id",deref(x.column_value) from TEST_OBJ_TABLE t, table(t."extension") x`

Note1. You should avoid declaring attribute using double quote. Db becomes case sensitive and it's not normal situation :)

Note2. I don't know why code formatting is not working today

Question. Why are you trying to use such complicated construction?